# Can't install CiviCRM extension with fresh install of Joomla

Tags: installation

When I attempt to install CiviCRM (5.69.2) in my Jooma (5.0.2) instance I receive the following error:

```
Compile Error: Declaration of Psr\Log\NullLogger::log($level, $message, array $context = []) must be compatible with Psr\Log\AbstractLogger::log($level, Stringable|string $message, array $context = []): void
```

I'm on PHP version 8.2.4.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's a conflict between the copy of `psr/log` bundled with Civi and one already being used on your site. Can you give more details about which version exactly is present on your site and whether it's part of Joomla core or a Joomla plugin?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how do I find that detail? Is it the composer.json inside the `com_civicrm` folder?

Comment: It could be anywhere! But that's a good place to start. A global grep of all `.json` files for the string "psr/log" would find it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

NO, it's a CiviCRM error in com_civicrm/admin/civicrm/vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/NullLogger.php, there line 26 must be changed form `public function log($level, $message, array $context = array())` to `public function log($level, $message, array $context = []): void`.

Replace () through [], add the `: void` then CiviCRM installs without errors and works like a charm.

I tested this and can confirm this works.

Comment: Added a comment in the already opened issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/joomla/-/issues/54

Comment: @thejason: I'd suggest to wait for (hopefully) the next CiviCRM release. The change I proposed needs to be reviewed and implemented. In case you know CiviCRM and your environment very well, you could change the file using the code above, recompile and reinstall it. A solution that ALWAYS works is to install CiviCRM on Joomla 4.4.x and then upgrade Joomla to version 5.0.x.